# android_camera_tutorial consuming high memory (raw_image) slow image refresh

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, The android_camera tutorial memory consumption is too high. I just upgraded to new version of rosjava_android. I am using one mobile device as RosCameraPreview node which runs roscore and transmits images to another android device (motorola xoom) which subscribes to the message. Both seem to consume high memory and I can see GC constantly running. The frame changes approximately 30 seconds on the ImageTransport side
I rarely see the message onFlyCompress. I think this version publishes /camera/raw_image/compressed, that may be the issue, how can I subscribe to /camera/image/compressed ?

The previous version I had was working very well. I recently upgraded to new version. Any ideas to improve the performance ?
Regards
GOPI

06 23:10:27.667: D/dalvikvm(24445): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1226K, 53% free 3950K/8263K, external 2486K/2773K, paused 2ms+2ms
04-06 23:10:27.977: D/dalvikvm(24445): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1226K, 53% free 3950K/8263K, external 2486K/2773K, paused 2ms+5ms
04-06 23:05:12.377: D/dalvikvm(24445): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1226K, 49% free 3951K/7623K,

external 2486K/2773K, paused 3ms+2ms

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31405/android_camera_tutorial-consuming-high-memory-(raw_image)-slow-image-refresh/) by [gopinath](https://answers.ros.org/users/1580/gopinath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=97

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2013-06-14**:
I have the same problem but with image_transport. I'm sorry but can't see any solution in your post, damonkohler

EDIT: I found solution here: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=141